# Link tag with rel=canonical pointing to the page itself

Tags: html, seo, rel

I have a page for which I have translated the link with UrlManager (in Yii), and now I find myself with two Urls pointing to same page and the same content. This will affect my webpage ranking.

What I wish to do is to put a `link tag` with the attribute `rel="canonical"` in the `head tag` that tell the search engine which of the two is the page to be indexed (the new one which has been translated).

The problem with this method is that this page will have a link tag to itself, and I dont think it would be a good solution?

Is it possible to have a page which contains a link tag with rel="canonical" and href attribute pointing to itself.

Comment: That's perfectly fine and normal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found the answer in this link:
[rel canonical tag back to the same page the tag is on?](http://www.seomoz.org/q/rel-canonical-tag-back-to-the-same-page-the-tag-is-on)

And the answer is that it's possible to have a link tag to same page the link is on.